# Plesk IIS_IUSER permission

Tags: windows, iis, permissions, plesk, application-pool

I want to know one thing: when I am creating any account it need to change the default application pool to the new application pool and `IIS_IUSER`permission then it's working.

I want when I am adding any domain in my `PLESK` panel all domains get new application pool and `IIS_IUSER` permission. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Dedicated IIS Application Pool for Your Websites. For that login to your plesk >> subscriptions >> websites & domains >> select the option 'Dedicated IIS Application Pool for Your Websites' >> switch on >> Ok.

It will create a dedicated application pool for your domain like this "yourdomain.com(domain)(pool)".